# Storing values from dropdowns to Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on an attendance module. Initially, it will show the list of all students along with a dropdown having options Present/Absent. The faculty member will choose Present/Absent accordingly & submit the same.

I am having problem in storing the corresponding values to the DB.

```
$sql = "select a.student_id, r.student_name, r.section, r.group_name, a.$subject from result.$batch r, attendance.$batch a where a.student_id = r.student_id AND r.section='$section'";
$c   = 1;
$result1 = $result->query($sql);
if ($result1->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) 
    { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>$c </td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['student_id']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['student_name']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['section']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['group_name']}</td>";
        echo "<td>
                  <select class='dropdown' id='attend' name='attend[$c]' > <option value='1'>Present</option> <option value='2'>Absent</option>
              </td>";
        echo '</tr>';
        ++$c;
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "No Results Found";
}
```

Can someone please help me with the updation code. Updation is to be made in the table $batch (batch is a variable containing Table Name to use) and column $subject (contains variable name).

Comment: So you want to update the attendance real time? You can use javascript and Ajax to achieve your desired result. And what is also the table structure where you store the attendance? Or at least provide us your `UPDATE` query.

Comment: for realtime updation, use ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you can do one thing.when user clicks on the check-box to mark absent or present, save it into an array using Javascript like :
 `onclick='array.push(this.id);'`

this would push the id of current element to an array in Javascript.
When you finally submit the form, just do this,

`onsubmit="passValues();"`
in script tag, do this

`function passValues()
{
 var x = array // the array to which elements were pushed
 document.getElementById('someBlankElement').innerHTML = "<input type='hidden' value = 'display array here' name='get_this_name_through_php_when_form_submits' >"
}`

and done !

Comment: i wrote for checkbox, you can do the same for dropdown too